# semantic issue Unused Parameter 'format' warnings xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode4.6

In .m file i am getting this warning not an error

semantic issue Unused Parameter 'format'

getting as an unused parameter in this .m file after opening this in xcode4.6

```
+ (ParsedResult *)parsedResultForString:(NSString *)s
                                 format:(BarcodeFormat)format
```

Answer (score 1):

This warning means that the parameter `format` is never used in your function.
To get rid of that warning, you can do one of the following.

a) Put special `#pragma` to suppress the warning in certain function, just put it underneath your function implementation, i.e.:

```
+ (ParsedResult *)parsedResultForString:(NSString *)s
                             format:(BarcodeFormat)format
{
    #pragma unused (format)
    // ... your code here ...
```

b) Globally switch off this warning in the project. Go to your project settings or target settings => `Build Settings` => `Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2 - Warnings - All languages` => `Unused Parameters`, set it to `No`.